# Java PriorityQueue behaviour with 3 elements in the Queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

As per the definition of PriorityQueue, it says :

> The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their
>   natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction
>   time, depending on which constructor is used.

But when I am trying with 3 elements in the Queue, the elements does not appear to be sorted properly.

```
    Queue<Integer> q2 = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    q2.add(9);
    q2.add(7);
    q2.add(8);

    Iterator<Integer> i = q2.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Integer e = i.next();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Output :

```
7
9
8
```

[edit]
If the number of elements is 4, the sorting appears to be correct

```
    q2.add(9);
    q2.add(7);
    q2.add(8);
    q2.add(5);

    Iterator<Integer> i = q2.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Integer e = i.next();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Outputs:

```
5
7
8
9
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are using `Iterator` which does not guarantee any order during traversal of the queue. The Javadoc of `PriorityQueue` says:

> The Iterator provided in method `iterator()` is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()`).

When you poll the queue, you'll get the correct order:

```
while (!q2.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println(q2.poll());
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Is something wrong with this answer?